# How to make request with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I am trying to make transferwise api request to get currency rates. how this code looks in python?

```
curl -X GET "https://api.sandbox.transferwise.tech/v1/rates?source=EUR&target=USD" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer <your api token>"
```

Comment: checkout the docs https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that `https://api.sandbox.transferwise.tech` is the Base URL Sandbox (just for tests) **not the Live version**, so it only works with sandbox accounts (`https://sandbox.transferwise.tech/login2/`). Also, you gotta create your own token API in Setting (more information [here](https://transferwise.com/help/articles/2958229/whats-an-api-token)).

After you have your token API set up, you can **put it into an Environment Variable (.env)**, for the sake of security.

To use the Live Version, instead of the Sandbox, use this Base URL: `https://api.transferwise.com`

`app.py` (without environment variables):

```
import requests

API_TOKEN = <your API token here>

# Using Base URL LIVE
url = "https://api.transferwise.com/v1/rates?source=EUR&target=USD"

headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {API_TOKEN}'}

response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

print(response)
```

Comment: This is the first place I found advice regarding sandbox vs live, and it seems to be the solution to OP's problem as well... This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

url = "https://api.sandbox.transferwise.tech/v1/rates?source=EUR&target=USD"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <your api token>'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Also, please don't share your API tokens here.

Comment: yes i know but its an error i get:

b'{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"9dcdf463-be7f-41e4-bcc1-1393e71ea10e"}'
is my token invalid? can you please try and get information with my token or yours?

Comment: According to this message, yes it is an invalid token.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

token = "9dcdf463-be7f-41e4-bcc1-1393e71ea10e"
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}
url = "https://api.sandbox.transferwise.tech/v1/rates?source=EUR&target=USD"

response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

Comment: Did it worked for you? I got:     {'error': 'invalid_token', 'error_description': '9dcdf463-be7f-41e4-bcc1-1393e71ea10e'}

Comment: seems like token is invalid. you should get a new token.

Comment: I tried with second token too. Can you please do it with your token and give me screenshot of python compiler? i am interested in how it works

Comment: it also gives me the same error `{'error': 'invalid_token', 'error_description': '9dcdf463-be7f-41e4-bcc1-1393e71ea10e'}
`